# Combinatorial Games

Tags: combinatorics

There are n coins on a table and 2 players take turns to remove 1,3 or 4 coins. A player wins if he removes the last coin. Find all winning and losing positions.

b.t.w. I am a little confused about whether 7 is a winning or losing position. Also does there ever exist an undetermined position in such combinatorial games?

Comment: I'm still a bit stuck on this question. I'd be glad if anyone could please give me some advice or hints.

Comment: There are no undetermined positions in this game. Go backwards: knowing that $1,3,4$ are winning positions, then...

Answer (score 0):

If you only have doubts for $n=7$, then notice that either $n=6,4,3$ are forced victories for the person who has the turn, in which case the first to go loses by force, or one of them is a forced loss for the person who has the turn, in which case the first to go may choose any of those (I advise the smallest, because maybe he has to go eat).

Similarly, there are no "unclear positions", because if all the positions with $n<k$ have been determined, then so is the one with $k$ coins, and (strong?) induction concludes (notice that $k=0$ is a forced loss).

Comment: so can we say that any positions that result in only winning positions for player 2 is a losing position for player 1?

Comment: That seems like the definition of being "winning (by force)" or "losing (by force)".

Comment: cool, that clears things up a lot thanks:)

Comment: @Lil_Phil Though I think you might have an easier time thinking in terms of "winning for the person who has the turn" and "losing for the person who has the turn", because if you reason in terms of "winning/losing for the player who made the first move of the game" you end up having to factor in the length of the game so far, which is unnecessary here because the game depends only on the current position.